# Android Studio 2.2 Native Development Migration Issue

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

Before making the switch to AS 2.2, I have the following structure to implement my C

```
app/src/main/jni/Android.mk
app/src/main/jni/Application.mk
app/src/main/jni/headers/*
app/src/main/jni/cfiles*.cc
```

in which case everything built fine. However, after upgrading to AS 2.2, I cannot build any apk and always recieve the following error:

> `Execution failed for task':app:transformNative_libsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug
>   java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)`

Does anyone know why this is? I cannot seem to find a work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I felt like a lot of these solutions were overkill. Sorry for answering my own question, but the actual solution was taken from just about every post here!

Much like what @GregT said, what worked for me was upgrading the NDK package that I had installed. And, doing so actually modified the `*.mk` files, much like @Matthew_Bondarchuk's answer.

Consequently, like @aaronvargas said, this is a bug; specifically, the Android NDK system was not updated in conjunction with the upgrades that Android Studio 2.2 instanced. This causes an incompatibility with the Android build tools, much like @Michael_Jess said.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem in my project )
try to add this into your build.gradle (module)

```
    externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path 'src/main/jni/Application.mk'
    }
}
```

[Link Gradle to your native library](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#create-cmake-script)

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a try.

Comment: This removed the error `Execution failed for task':app:transformNative_libsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug`, but now I get `Android NDK: WARNING: There are no modules to build in this project!` messages so I may need to change how the native code in my app is compiled with AS and Gradle.  I'm trying to build the Makeblock app for Android (https://github.com/Makeblock-official/Makeblock-App-For-Android) which contains native C code.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded to AS 2.2 this morning and had the same error. Upgrading the NDK solved it for me. You can upgrade via SDK Manager now, instructions are here:

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#download-ndk

Also make sure that your "local.properties" file is pointing to the right NDK location. Example Windows local.properties:

```
ndk.dir=C\:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\ndk-bundle
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug with the 2.2.0 and up version of the gradle android build tools. Causing me issues on our CI environment.

Please star the bug below!

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=223162

for now we're reverting to an old version of the tools to 2.1.3

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. And i did start the bug this actually solves the issues for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same error today, in a [Rajawali](https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali) project - that is, we did not implement native components but used a library that implements some native OpenGL components. I suppose this is somehow linked to an Android Studio update (on that machine, it was `2.2.3`), but I cannot clearly tell at this point. It just "suddenly stopped working."

However, we needed to upgrade to the experimental Android build tools *and* apply Mike's fix above to get it working. A (somewhat outdated) migration guide can be found [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental#TOC-Migrating-from-Traditional-Android-Gradle-Plugin). For reference, we needed to adjust only `build.gradle` and `app/build.gradle`, which now look as follows:

```
// build.gradle
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.8.3'
        // used to be: 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

...and

```
//app/build.gradle
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
// used to be 'com.android.application'

// android() migrated according to guide
// note that buildConfigFields() is missing, because it lead to errors
model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.projecttango.experiments.augmentedrealitysample"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel 19
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 19
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.pro"))
            }
        }

        productFlavors {
            create("flavor1") {
                applicationId "com.app"
            }
        }

        sources {
            main {
                java {
                    source {
                        srcDir "src"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Fix suggested by Mike above
        ndk {
            platformVersion 21
        }
    }
}

// Remaining Rajawali "noise"
def external_lib_prefix = null
if (project.hasProperty("Tango.catkin_devel_prefix")) {
    external_lib_prefix = project.property("Tango.catkin_devel_prefix")
} else {
    // Building in standalone sample form.
    external_lib_prefix = "../../TangoReleaseLibs"
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs external_lib_prefix + '/aar'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: external_lib_prefix + '/jar', include: ['**/*.jar'])
    compile (name: 'tango_support_java_lib', ext: 'aar')
    compile 'org.rajawali3d:rajawali:1.1.668@aar'
}
```

Once you are done, make sure to synchronize the Gradle project in Android Studio. Otherwise, when you try to run immediately, you will see something like `Task 'generateDebugSources' not found in project ':app'`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried various tweaks, the one that fixed the issue for me was changing the platformVersion from the "19" it was set to, to "21" in the model{android{ndk section of the app's build.gradle. This will only be relevant in the Experimental version. I'm building with compileSdkVersion set to 24 and buildToolsVersion at 24.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your configuration of *`build.gralde`* in app-module:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
```

Here is my configuration of `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion` which makes effect to me, that you need to update your configuration of `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion` to the most match one to your `gradle-plugin version`.

**In a word, once you upgrade your `gradle-plugin version` ,you should also upgrade your configuration in `build.gradle`to make sure that you can get a correct result.**