# Gradle error - app:transformNative_libsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug

Tags: android, gradle, nullpointerexception, android-gradle-plugin

When I try to run my application

```
"Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformNative_libsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)"
```

Error pops up
I've tried solving this by following someone's answer and I changed targetSDKVersion and compileSdkVersion but when I change them, 5 errors pop up instead of 1 and they're nothing like this error ( I think this happens because the app uses stuff from api23)

How can I solve this?

Comment: This is a google bug See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/41048721/114549

Comment: I am facing the same problem ? Have you got solusion ? then please tell me